# Behaviour of a Sequence of Integrals $\int_{0}^{\pi}f(x)\sin(nx)dx$ at Infinity

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, trigonometric-integrals

> Describe the behaviour of the sequence $(a_n)$ for $n\to\infty$
>   with 
>   $$a_n=\int_{0}^{\pi}f(x)\sin(nx)dx$$
>   and $f(x)$ an arbitrary continously differentiable function.

Can I argue, that with the Mean Value Theorem

$$\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin(xn)f(x)dx=f(\xi)\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin(xn)dx=f(\xi)\frac{1-cos(\pi n)}{n}$$

the sequence converges

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigg [\ \frac{1-cos(\pi n)}{n}\bigg ]f(\xi)\to 0$$
?

Comment: Ever heard of Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma?

Comment: Try integrating by parts.